# Why does this code not switch cin and cout with file streams?

Tags: c++, ifstream, cout, cin, ofstream

Below are two pieces of code. One works, one does not, I'd like to know why. I apologise in advance for the lack of comments and awful variable names but right now this language is really grinding my gears.

```
// File1.cpp (contains relevant includes)
// Works! It writes to out.txt and appears to use in.txt correctly
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int num;
    std::ifstream in("in.txt");
    std::streambuf* cinbuf = std::cin.rdbuf();
    std::cin.rdbuf(in.rdbuf());

    std::ofstream out("out.txt");
    std::streambuf* coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();
    std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());

    cout << "Give me a number: ";
    cin >> num;

    std::cin.rdbuf(cinbuf);
    std::cout.rdbuf(coutbuf);

    return 0;
}

// File2.cpp (contains relevant includes)
// Does not work! Outputs nothing to out.txt.
class TestWithStdIO {
        std::streambuf* cinbuf;
        std::streambuf* coutbuf;
    public:
        TestWithStdIO(const char* inFile, const char* outFile) {
            std::ifstream in(inFile);
            cinbuf = std::cin.rdbuf();
            std::cin.rdbuf(in.rdbuf());

            std::ofstream out(outFile);
            coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();
            std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
        }
        ~TestWithStdIO() {
            std::cin.rdbuf(cinbuf);
            std::cout.rdbuf(coutbuf);
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int num;
    TestWithStdIO* ioTest = new TestWithStdIO("in.txt", "out.txt");
    cout << "Give me a number: ";
    cin >> num;
    delete ioTest;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `in` and `out` only exist on the stack within the constructor call. They "die" as soon as the constructor is finished. Perhaps make them member variables too (and pass the filename to the [initializer list](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/) to open them).

Comment: @BoBTFish You should make that an answer, since it _is_ what's wrong.  (Well, the fact that he dynamically allocates `TestWithStdIO` is also wrong.  `TestWithStdIO` is basically RAII, and RAII and dynamic allocation seem to be constradictory to me.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Not to mention that such a raw pointer is not exception safe.

Comment: @BoBTFish Nice! Thank you so much! Make it an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: @syam So you'd make it a smart pointer?  An RAII class to manage an RAII class?  Almost by definition, an RAII class shouldn't be allocated dynamically.

Comment: @JamesKanze I definitely wouldn't make this a smart pointer, I was just pointing out *another* flaw in addition to your remark. :) Just to be clear, the fact that OP is using dynamic allocation is not incorrect per se (even though I agree with you, it should be on the stack), but this very situation with raw pointers is definitely incorrect because it is not exception safe. Again, I'm just talking about correctness here, not good design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std::[io]fstreams` `in` and `out` have local scope (or *automatic storage duration*) inside the `TestWithStdIO` constructor. They are destroyed (and the files closed), along with their contained buffers, at the end of the function, leaving you with dangling pointers inside`cin` and `cout`.

Consider instead making `in` and `out` members of `TestWithStdIO`, something like this:

```
class TestWithStdIO {
        std::streambuf* cinbuf;
        std::streambuf* coutbuf;

        std::ifstream in_;  // <-- member
        std::ofstream out_; // <-- member
    public:
        TestWithStdIO(const std::string& inFile, const std::string& outFile) :
            in_(inFile), out_(outFile) // <-- initializer list
        {
            cinbuf = std::cin.rdbuf();
            std::cin.rdbuf(in_.rdbuf());

            coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();
            std::cout.rdbuf(out_.rdbuf());
        }
        ~TestWithStdIO() {
            std::cin.rdbuf(cinbuf);
            std::cout.rdbuf(coutbuf);
        }
};
```

You might need `in(inFile.c_str())` and the equivalent for `out` if you only have `C++03` support.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, there is no need to dynamically allocate the `TestWithStdIO` instance, and in fact it is likely to be a source of bugs. Just do

```
TestWithStdIO ioTest ("in.txt", "out.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

In `TestWithStdIO::TestWithStdIO()`, The stream buffer pointed to by `in.rdbuf()` is destroyed together with `in` (i.e. at the end of the constructor).